# OpenGL: All planets have the same speed around the sun when animating

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, glut

I'm trying to make an animation of the Solarsystem in GLUT, but somehow all the planets are flying around the sun at the same speed, while they all have different values.

I'm new at OpenGL/GLUT so if you could explain your answer it would be appreciated :)

This is my animation method:

```
void renderScene(void) 
{
glClearDepth(1);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

if (spinMode) {
    // Update the animation state
    HourOfDay += AnimateIncrement;
    DayOfYear += AnimateIncrement/24.0;

    HourOfDay = HourOfDay - ((int)(HourOfDay/24))*24;
    DayOfYear = DayOfYear - ((int)(DayOfYear/365))*365;
}

glLoadIdentity();

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION,LightPosition);

glRotatef(15.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

//Drawing the sun
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, f);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
//glPushMatrix();
gluSphere(quad[0], 1.0f, 64, 64);
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glPopMatrix();

//Drawing mercurius
glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste parameter afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[1], 0.2f, 64, 64);
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glPopMatrix();

//Drawing the earth
glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste paramater afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[2], 0.4f, 64, 64);
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glPopMatrix();

//Drawing the earth1
glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste paramater afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[2], 0.6f, 64, 64);
glRotatef(360.0*3*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glPopMatrix();

//Drawing the earth2
glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(4.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste paramater afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[2], 0.3f, 64, 64);
glRotatef(360.0*4*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glPopMatrix();

//Drawing the earth3
glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(4.3, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste paramater afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[2], 0.75f, 64, 64);
glRotatef(360.0*2*DayOfYear/365.00, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glPopMatrix();

// Flush the pipeline, and swap the buffers
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();

if ( singleStep ) {
    spinMode = GL_FALSE;
}

glutPostRedisplay();        // Request a re-draw for animation purposes
}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is dark matter in the solar system?

Comment: I'd probably replace "in GLUT" with "using GLUT", just for future references :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call order is wrong. So every planet will rotate around its center along the y axis.
Take mercurius for example.

```
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);//Move to new position
gluSphere(quad[1], 0.2f, 64, 64);
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //Rotate y axis
```

The correct order should be

```
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //Rotate y axis
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0); //Move to new position
gluSphere(quad[1], 0.2f, 64, 64);
```

However, if this is the only error, your planet will not rotate around the sun at all. What make your planet rotate around the sun is a second error, you forget to push the matrix before performing transformation with the sun. Therefore, every planet inherit these transformation.
The correct code should be

```
//Put every global transformation here


//Drawing the sun
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(360.0 * DayOfYear / 365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //This will self-rotate the sun
gluSphere(quad[0], 1.f, 64, 64);
glPopMatrix();

//Drawing mercurius
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste parameter afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[1], 0.2f, 64, 64);
glPopMatrix();

//Drawing the earth1
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
glRotatef(360.0*3*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste paramater afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[2], 0.6f, 64, 64);
glPopMatrix();
```

Also you should only use glutSwapBuffers() in your main rendering function, and glutPostRedisplay() in callbacks. Don't use them both in the same function.

Answer (score 1):

Note 360.0*DayOfYear/365.0 is in each of your planet's rotations.  If you would like them to rotate at different speeds then the amount you rotate them needs to be different.  Change 365.0 to a different number to produce years of different lengths. A larger number will create a longer year and a smaller number will produce a shorter year.

Comment: This is the problem; not all years equal 365 (not even earth (365.25)); Mercery: 88 A year on Venus lasts 224.7 Earth days, which is 62% of the length of a year on Earth. (A day on Venus is 243 days, so Venus’ day is actually longer than its year!) Kepler's 3rd Law: P^2 = a^3. see: <http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/planets_orbits_table.html>

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually render the sphere **after** you call `glTranslate` and `glRotate`. Right now, you're doing it inbetween, so it'll just ignore the rotation!

For example:

```
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste parameter afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[1], 0.2f, 64, 64);
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

should be

```
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste parameter afstand tot zon
gluSphere(quad[1], 0.2f, 64, 64); // <-- after you rotate!
```

Comment: I think your call order will rotate the planet around its core, not around the sun.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not rotating the objects themselves, rather than their position relative to a central point? Try changing the order of the statements between `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`.

Comment: As I said, I'm really new to this and the purpose of glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() are not really clear to me. I tried different combinations and putting them on different places in the code, but it's no use. I was hoping someone here could post the answer and explain to me how it works.

Comment: @Galip: Sorry, some effort required. :) Did you read the OpenGL red book? All the answers are there.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually rotating and translating all objects you have rendered. I recommend to increment each planet uniquely so they will rotate at different speed. You may create a structure bearing all the necessary information like rotation and revolution speed and use the structure data to create all the planets. In that way, in your if(spinMode), you can do something like mars.revolve(). This idea is for those new at OpenGL.